# Checkout Shipping Methods : fedex

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I have tested with IE, Chrome, and Firefox for FedEx shipping methods stability issue. In all three browsers we found that during onepage checkout, not all 4 shipping methods we have are listed on the page. Sometimes there are only 2 or 3 methods available, and occasionally it shows no shipping methods and the checkout process got stuck. i would like to troubleshoot this issue to make sure all four shipping methods

how can  i fix it

Comment: Are you using the default theme?

Comment: no custom theme

Comment: So the first thing is to switch to the default theme and see if it still does the same thing